# Can one application using Oracle Client 12 communicate (for example, run queries) to an Oracle Server 19 (database)? Are they compatible?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c

I'm upgrading Oracle Server (database) to 19 and plan to let Oracle Client 12 on my application. Will it works fine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that combination is supported. See here for more info: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=430033747920845&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=BULLETIN&id=207303.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=540lr4pnf_4